# In OpenCV 3.3.1, how to use pass2Only option of MSER

Tags: opencv, mser

OpenCV version 3.3.1 has an implementation of MSER algorithm, and one possible option is setPass2Only, but it's not specify in the documentation what is it for: https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d28/classcv_1_1MSER.html#aba564613ffdcd6a89ef0e381c4b02c48
I don't understand exactly how is the implementation of the algorithm, but what I understand from what I see, is that one could use that option to run just the "brighter to darker" part of the algorithm, but if this is like this, how is it if I want to run "darker to brighter" only?

Comment: Jus a quick question are you referring python opencv? Or the original c++

Comment: It's the same, the Python part is just a wrap for the C++

Comment: Python doesn't include all features

Comment: mser.setPass2Only(True) works in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MSER algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximally_stable_extremal_regions) consists of 2 steps:

- MSER+ : darker to brighter
- MSER- : brighter to darker.

You can see in the [OpenCV source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/29e4a4940dd81b22b26cbb51a2673d8c17f9f57d/modules/features2d/src/mser.cpp#L1062) that `pass2only` parameters allows to execute only one step, namely MSER-.

If you want to execute only the MSER+ step

1. invert the input image
2. run the MSER- step on the inverted image